# Doing CRUD on sub-sub-documents using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm a beginner learning MEAN stack and I'm trying to build a basic forum in order to become familiar with this stack. So far, I've gotten everything to work except sub-sub-docs. I'm having trouble doing CRUD on comments within posts within topics. I've already done a lot of searching and nothing looks exactly how I need. So my question is, how would you implement this? I know there are probably multiple ways to do this, such as using refs instead of sub-sub-docs, but seeing as I've already written code for things like CRUD topics and CRUD posts within topics using sub-docs, I'd rather not use refs if I'd have to go back and change my code.

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;
var uri = "...";
mongoose.connect(uri);

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  content: String,
  author: UserSchema
});

var PostSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  author: UserSchema,
  comments: [CommentSchema]
});

var TopicSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  title: String,
  moderator: UserSchema,
  posts: [PostSchema]
});

var Topic = mongoose.model('Topic', TopicSchema);

var app = express();

app.delete('/topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId', function(req, res) {
    //What goes here?
});

app.put('/topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId', function(req, res) {
    //What goes here?
});

app.post('/topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId', function(req, res) {
    //What goes here?
});

app.get('/topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId', function(req, res) {
    //What goes here?
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to not embed your objects too deeply. Maybe create a comment collection, it would be more handy. 
Anyway, if you want to use one mongoose operation you have to loop through posts before, to know the index you want to update. Let's suppose it's 0, to remove the comment:

```
Topic.findOneAndUpdate(
  { id: req.params.topicId },
  { $pull: { 'posts.0.comments': { _id: req.params._id } }},
  { safe: true }
)
```

That's why it's not really what you want.

You can change directly the object and save it :

```
Topic.findOne({ _id: req.params.topicId })
  .then(topic => {

    const { posts } = topic
    let comments
    for (let i = 0, l = posts.length; i < l; ++i) {

      if (posts[i]._id.toString() === req.params.postId) {
        comments = posts[i].comments
        for (let j = 0, m = comments.length; j < m; ++j) {
          if (comments[j]._id.toString() === req.params.commentId) {
            comments.splice(j, 1)
            break
           }
        })

        break
      }

    }

    return topic.save()
  })
```

Not really ideal because it does not leverage mongodb indexes and research to make these operations. But you could use:

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  id: ObjectId,
  postId: ObjectId,
  content: String,
  author: UserSchema
})

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema)

Comment.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.params.commentId, postId: req.params.postId }, { ... })
```

Comment: app.put('/topics/:topicId/posts/:postId/comments/:commentId', requireLogin, function(req, res) {
 var topicId = req.params.topicId;
 var postId = req.params.postId;
 var commentId = req.params.commentId;
 User.findOne({"email": req.session.user.email}, function(err, user) {
   if (user.role == "user" || user.role == "admin") {
     Topic.findById(topicId, function(err, topic) {
       topic.posts.id(postId).comments.id(commentId).content = req.body.content;
       topic.save(function(err) {
         if (err) console.log(err);
         res.status(204).end();
       });
     });
   }
 });
});

Comment: However, I think the last example you gave seems the most elegant and straightforward (and probably also efficient) way to do it, so I'll probably change to use that instead.